# lmer: Random factor is treated as grouping factor?

Tags: r, lme4

I'm trying to create a model in R using `lmer`. I have 40 subjects (`VPN` in my code) who each evaluate three correlated sentence types (`SH`, `SM`, `SP`) on a 5 point Likert scale.
Here's how the data looks (for every parameter, there are 40 evaluations, I just shortened it here for better clarity):

```
     VPN  parameter evaluation.likert
1     1       SH1      2
2     2       SH1      4
3     3       SH1      5
4     4       SH1      3
...
5     1       SM1      4
6     2       SM1      2
7     3       SM1      2
8     4       SM1      5
...
9     1       SP1      1
10    2       SP1      1
11    3       SP1      3
12    4       SP1      5
...
```

IMO, I need to treat subjects as random factors to account for the repeated measures which is why I use this code in R:

```r
model <- lmer(SH*SM*SP ~ VPN + (1|VPN), data=data)
```

Now I get the error message

> number of levels of each grouping factor must be < number of observations (problems: VPN).

Why is `VPN` treated as a grouping factor and what would be the right code?

Comment: Your proposed model formula is wrong in several ways. First you need to clarify: Isn't VPN (whatever that is) your dependent variable? The grouping variable of the random effect should be the subject IDs.

Comment: Hi Roland, many thanks for your quick answer and sorry I didn't include the explanation for VPN. VPN are in fact my subjects. I want to find out if the three different sentence types are evaluated differently by my subjects.

Comment: I suspect that your data is not in long format. If that is the case, your first step should be reshaping your data. The formula should probably look like `value ~ variable + (variable | VPN)`. However, I'm also doubtful that you should use `lmer` with a 5 point Likert scale variable as the dependent variable. However, I can't advise for a better approach because I don't work with this kind of data.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Roland, thank you! I think that the data format is correct. But as you're pointing out, I'm also not sure, that ```lmer``` is the right way to go. Many thanks again!

Comment: No, if you ever thought your code might be correct, the data cannot be in the correct input format for regression models.

Comment: Can you please post your data in text (i.e. edit your question to cut-and-paste the data into a code block), rather than as an image? Images are unsearchable and inaccessible to screen readers ...

Comment: @Roland, you were completely right, the data was not in the correct form. Thank you for pointing it out again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`VPN` is being treated as a grouping variable because that's what you specified: in the random effect specification `(f|g)`, the variable `g` is the grouping variable (in your case, `f`==`1` specifies variation across groups in the intercept).

@Roland is correct that you need to reshape your data.  Your data look like this:

```r
set.seed(101)
dd <- data.frame(VPN=1:40, 
         SH1 = sample(1:5, 40, replace = TRUE),
         SP1 = sample(1:5, 40, replace = TRUE),
         SM1 = sample(1:5, 40, replace = TRUE))
```

There are many ways to reshape data in R, here is how I would do it:

```r
dd_long <- tidyr::pivot_longer(dd,
        cols = -VPN,  ## VPN is the ID variable
        names_to = "type",
        values_to = "value")
```

- *If* you wanted to treat your Likert values as numeric (possibly a bad idea), the simplest model would be

```r
lme4::lmer(value ~ 0 + type + (1|VPN))
```

This fits a separate intercept for each sentence type.

- I can't see how it makes sense to try to evaluate interactions among sentence types (`SM*SH*SP`), because based on the data we can see, each individual observation is of a particular individual observing a particular sentence type - more than one sentence type never applies to a single observation ... ? Perhaps there are aspects of your data that you haven't shown us?
- The *maximal model* would also allow for variation among individuals in the response to sentence type, with within-individual correlation in the response variation:

```r
lme4::lmer(value ~ 0 + type + (type|VPN),
   data = data_long)
```

However, with 40 subjects you may have trouble fitting 6 covariance parameters (3 types → (3*(3+1)/2 parameters). See Barr et al. 2013, Matuschek et al. 2017 ...

As @Roland says, it's probably better to deal with these data as *ordinal* data, e.g. using a *cumulative link model*:

```r
library(ordinal)
clmm(value ~ 0 + type + (type|VPN), data = data_long)
```

Comment: Hi Ben, thank you so much for your help. You're right, trying to treat the likert scales as anything other than ordinal does not make sense. I tried it with your clmm-code and it now works. Makes me really rellay happe, thank you!

Comment: @Carl_Menzies I encourage you to show your appreciation by voting on the answer (see arrows on the upper left) and clicking the check mark to signal that your question is answered to your satisfaction.

Comment: Absolutely, thank you, Roland! I still need to find my way around stackoverflow.